# Javascript math giving incorrect results, how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

So I have an issue with Javascript where it is giving me the wrong numbers when I am executing a function. Basically I have it set so my "Total" is equal to the "Total" plus "persec", persec is the number I wish to have added to "Total" every second. So if "persec" is equal to 4, I want it to add 4 to "Total" every second.

I have a for loop that acts as my timer to click a hidden button the is set to take whatever the persec is and add it to my total. My problem is that after the persec passes a value of 1, it starts to add incorrectly. For example if I have persec set to 2, my total will increase by 4 every second. It should only increase by 2. And for example if persec is set to 3 it will add 9 each second. It seems like it is adding the square of persec to the total and I have no idea why.

Here is the buttons and text that is edited with the Javascript below:

```
<p>Per second: <span id="persec">0</span></p>
<p>Total: <span id="total">0</span></p>
<button id="totalholder" hidden="true"></button>
```

Here is my "timer", it is in its own function that doesn't apply to the problem, which is why it seems out of place:

```
var totalCount;
clearInterval(totalCount);

    totalCount = setInterval(function () {
        if (persec > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < persec; i++) {
                $("#totalholder").click();
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
```

And here is the hidden button the timer presses:

```
$(function() {
$('#totalholder').click(function(){
    totalHolder1();
});

function totalHolder1() {
var persec = parseInt($('#persec').text());
var total = parseInt($('#total').text());

    total = isNaN(total) ? 0 : total + persec;

    $("#persec").text(persec);
    $("#total").text(total);
}
});
```

Comment: `persec` is a local variable in the `totalHolder` function. Why is your interval function trying to use it?

Comment: persec cannot be accessed as it's scope is only within the `totalHolder` method.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the loop in the timer function:

```
totalCount = setInterval(function() {
    var persec = parseInt($("#persec").text(), 10);
    if (persec > 0) {
        $("#totalholder").click();
    }
}, 1000);
```

In your original code, the click handler increases the total by `persec`, and the `for` loop was doing that `persec` times, which squares it. Since you don't want to do it multiple times, you don't need the loop.

Comment: looks like you're missing something on the `var parsec = ` line

Answer (score 0):

I just accidently fixed it.

All I had to do was change my for loop to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < persec; i = i + persec)
```

I am not sure why this fixed it, I have done it the other way before.

Comment: The problem is that you're looping `persec` times, and the click handler adds `persec` to the total each time. So that multiplies persec by persec.

Comment: Your new loop just runs one time. Why do you need a loop?

Comment: Yeah it's confusing the way I do it because I looked everywhere and found nothing on how to do what I wanted in a single function. I came up with the idea of just having the for loop click a hidden button that has my jquery math in it.

Comment: @Barmar It's not running one time, in my code above it's running every second.

Comment: The `for()` loop only iterates one time, because of your new increment.

Comment: @Barmar Oh? It's working perfectly fine on my end. It's running every second like I intend and it fixed the math issue.

Comment: I know it's working, but it's still wrong. Why do you need to use a `for` loop that's guaranteed to iterate exactly 1 time? Just get rid of the loop like in my answer.